# SQL: How to get the element from a delimited string by its index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this function (credit: [searchsqlserver](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-split-delimiter-separated-lists-in-SQL-Server#feedback)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000)             -- List of delimited items
    , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ','     -- delimiter that separates items
 ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))
     BEGIN
     DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
     WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
         BEGIN
         SELECT
         @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
            @sInputList,0)-1))),
         @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
            @sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))
         IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
            INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
         END

     IF LEN(@sInputList)> 0
     INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
     RETURN
     END
 GO
```

It takes as parameters a string and a delimiter and returns the delimited elements one by one.

```
select * from fnSplit('1,22,333', ',')    --   returns 1 22 333
```

I'll confess that I`m new to SQL and I simply can't follow the whole logic behind this function. What I'm trying to achieve is a function that has a third parameter(an index) and returns the element on the position mention by the index. For example:

```
select * from fnSplit('1 22 333 444 5555 666', ' ' , 2 ) --  333

select * from fnSplit('1 22 333 444 5555 666', ' ' , 0 ) --  1
```

Comment: If you are new to SQL, then first learn how to properly store values.  A delimited string is not the SQLish way to store a list of values.

Comment: `I simply can't follow the whole logic behind this function` Using multistatement table valued funtion for parsing string is not very efficient. Anyway http://rextester.com/RDU95829

Comment: To store a list of values I would use a table / #temp table / @table variable (`DECLARE @array TABLE(IntValue INT); INSERT @array (IntValue) VALUES (10), (20);`) or XML (ex: `DECLARE @x XML = '<array><item>10</item><item>20</item><array>'`)

Comment: @lad2025 make it an answer and I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multistatment table-valued UDF with loop to parse string is very inefficient.
 Better approaches: [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

---

Anyway if you want to adapt your function you could set `IDENTITY` column for table variable and then filter based on third parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000)             -- List of delimited items
    , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ','     -- delimiter that separates items
    ,@num INT
 ) RETURNS @List TABLE ( item VARCHAR(8000))
     BEGIN
     DECLARE @ListHelper AS TABLE(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), item VARCHAR(8000));
     DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
     WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
         BEGIN
         SELECT
         @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
            @sInputList,0)-1))),
         @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
            @sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))
         IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
            INSERT INTO @ListHelper SELECT @sItem
         END

     IF LEN(@sInputList)> 0
     INSERT INTO @ListHelper SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
     INSERT INTO @List
     SELECT item
     FROM @ListHelper
     WHERE id = @num
     RETURN
     END
 GO

select * from fnSplit('1 22 333 444 5555 666', ' ' , 3 );
--333
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/RDU95829)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

First off, looping splits are not efficient.

**Example with an Index Filter**

```
Select * 
 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('1 22 333 444 5555 666', ' '  )
 Where RetSeq=3
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
3       333
```

**Example without an Index Filter**

```
Select * 
 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('1 22 333 444 5555 666', ' '  )
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       1
2       22
3       333
4       444
5       5555
6       666
```

**The UDF used**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your split string function to include a row number:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit2(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000)             -- List of delimited items
    , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ','     -- delimiter that separates items
 ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))
     BEGIN
     DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000),
             @RowNumber int

     set @RowNumber = 0

     WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
         BEGIN


             SELECT
             @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
                @sInputList,0)-1))),
             @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,
                @sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))
             IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
                INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem, @RowNumber

            set @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1
         END

     set @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1

     IF LEN(@sInputList)> 0
     INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList, @RowNumber -- Put the last item in
     RETURN
     END
```